# Number of homomorphisms from $G = \langle x,y\mid x^{-1}yx=y^6\rangle$ to $S_5$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, finitely-generated, permutation-cycles, combinatorial-group-theory

We are asked to find the number of homomorphisms from $G$ to $S_5$. We consider the homomorphisms from $F_2$ (with generators $x$ and $y$) to $S_5$ and then we say that if image of $x$ and $y$ satisfy the relations, then this can be factored by a normal subgroup containing the relation.

The question is how to formally find the number of such homomorphisms $\phi: F_2 \to S_5$ satisfying $x^{-1}yx=y^6$ (I understand that the idea is to observe the order of $y$ and determine if $y$ is a $2, 3, 4, 5$ - cycle, but what to do with $x$) and how to act if (for example) the number of cases to consider for the images of $x, y$ is large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts which should surely get you started. Conjugation in the symmetric group preserves the cycle type, because it has the effect of permuting the underlying symbols. Thus, the relation $x^{-1}yx = y^6$ tells you that $y$ and $y^6$ have the same cycle type. Then we see which cycle types this is possible for. Since the cycle decomposition breaks down into disjoint cycles, this can only happen when each cycle in the decomposition has an order coprime to $6$, else raising it to the sixth power will result in some trivial cycles appearing, or else modify the cycle type, which we can't have. Since $6 = 2 \cdot 3$, this forces $y$ to be either a trivial cycle or a cycle of length $5$, as no other orders can appear. If it's the trivial cycle, then you can send $x$ anywhere. So one family of maps comes from $y \mapsto e, x \mapsto \text{anything}$ and this finds us $5!$ uninteresting maps.

Can you handle the other case?

Comment: Ah, woops. Thanks. I should fix that.

Comment: Yes, I get the general idea. However I still don't quite understand what happens with x? In our case when $y$ is a $5$-cycle, it is obvious that there are $5$ possibilities for x, but in a more general case (for example, if on another exercise we get that y can be a $3$ or $4$-cycle)? There it is not that easy.

Comment: In general, group presentations can be difficult to work with. It could very well be the case that in general, there are many cases that need to be considered. It's perfectly possible that for a general group, you can't say much of anything without a computer.

Comment: As for your question about how to choose x, suppose that we send y to some 5 cycle. Up to conjugation there is only one of these. Furthermore, raising a 5-cycle to the sixth power is the same as doing nothing to it. So we obtain $x^{-1}yx = y$, in other words, $x$ commutes with $y$. But we are in $S_5$, so there is not room for $x$ to be disjoint from $y$ unless it is the trivial element. So we find $4!$ more maps where $y$ goes to any $5$-cycle and $x$ must be trivial. The count is the 5! choices for permutations, modulo cyclic reordering.

Comment: I think in general, the centralizer in $S_n$ of a permutation of cycle type $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ has size $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i! i^{a_i}$.  The $a_i!$ term representing the "permutations of the $a_i$ $i$-cycles", and then $i^{a_i}$ representing $a_i$ independent choices of $i$ permutations preserving that cycle.  (And then, if you want the number of permutations conjugating $\sigma$ to $\sigma'$ where $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ have the same cycle type - the formula would be the same since the set of such permutations is a coset of the centralizer.)

Comment: A lot of these formulas can be graphically understood using Young Tableaux. That's where I learned what (little) I know about the symmetric group - from its representation theory. So you might try Fulton and Harris' chapter on the subject, if you want to see more stuff spelled out.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it much better now. Thanks for the answers and the book suggestion:)